# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation in Xcode not works

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following method in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:

```
-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 125, 125);
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(175, 20, 125, 125);
    NSLog(@"is portrait");
}else{
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 125, 125);
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(175, 155, 125, 125);
    NSLog(@"is landscape");
}
```

}

When I rotate the iOS simulator, I can see the log appears, which means that this method is called. However, the frames of buttons do not change. Can some one help me with it?

I found some related answers about changing the viewWillAppeaer method or things like that but none of them works out.

Comment: Set an Xcode breakpoint in that method and look to see if "`button1`" is a valid object or if it is "`NULL`".  You can instead add in a line like "`if(button1 == NULL) NSLog( @"why is button1 null?" );`" in your method and that will also tell you.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I just checked it and it is a valid object. I link the IBOutlet with the button in the storyboard. I didn't do anything fancy about it. So I think the problem is not about the object but about the method. Method changes a lot from Xcode4 to Xcode5. I am now following YouTube Tutorial of thenewboston and he is using Xcode4 I think. So the problem could be that this method got updated by Apple somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to force the buttons to redraw, which you can do via the addition of the two lines at the bottom of your method:

```
-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 125, 125);
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(175, 20, 125, 125);
        NSLog(@"is portrait");
    }else{
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 125, 125);
        button2.frame = CGRectMake(175, 155, 125, 125);
        NSLog(@"is landscape");
    }
    [button1 setNeedsDisplay];
    [button2 setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but it didn't work. I think you are heading for the right direction though.